# Android Build failed after adding Crosswalk to Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

Got excited about Ionic adding Crosswalk and now my project won't build. The project was compiling and working before updating and adding Crosswalk.  Anyone have any suggestions on how I can correct the error below? I prefer not to rollback. Thank goodness for version control :)

System information:

- OS: Windows 8
- Node Version: v0.10.32
- Cordova CLI: 4.2.0
- Ionic Version: 1.0.0-beta.14
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.3.1
- AngularJS v1.3.8

> WARNING [Project: :org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk:382300-xwalk_core_library] Current NDK support is deprecated. Alternative will be provided in the future.
>
> :mergeDebugResourcesC:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android.org.apache.cordova.engine
>   .crosswalk\rsgapp382300-xwalk_core_library\unspecified\debug\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_picker_advanced_select_handle.png
>
> ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
>
> Error: Failed to run command:
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe s-i C:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android.org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk 382300-xwalk_core_library\unspecified\debug\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_picker_advanced_select_handle.png -o C:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_picker_advanced_select_handle.png
>
> Error Code: 42
>
> Output: C:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android.org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk382300-xwalk_core_library\unspecified\debug\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_pick
>   er_advanced_select_handle.png
>
> ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
>
> :mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: Failed to run command: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android.org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk 382300-xwalk_core_library\unspecified\debug\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_picker_advanced_select_handle.png -o C:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_picker_advanced_select_handle.png
>
> Error Code: 42
>
> Output: C:\Users\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android.org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk382300-xwalk_core_library\unspecified\debug\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\color_picker_advanced_select_handle.png
>
> ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Comment: Could be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24876107/1091751)? Errors are similar, although those paths don't look like they're > 260 chars.  Does it work if you make the path shorter?

Comment: You were right! :) I placed the project folder under C:\ and the project built successfully. Please change your comment to an answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you were getting similar errors to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24875555/1091751), which was that on Windows, path names are restricted to 260 characters, so moving to a directory with a shorter path name should fix your issues.