# Warning. Current NDK support is depreciated. Alternative will be provided in the future

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Using Visual Studio 2015 RTM, default TypeScript Cordova (5.1.1) project and CrossWalk Cordova Plugin.  I get the following warning:

`Current NDK support is depreciated.  Alternative will be provided in the future`
[image]

The `project` Link in the error window is : https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22%5BProject%22);k(TargetOS-8.1)&rd=true

The warning doesn't appear to be affecting the build.  However, I'm not sure why the error is appearing.

Is this a Visual Studio 2015 issue?
Is this a Cordova problem?
Is this a CrossWalk problem?

Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

This definitely seems like a Crosswalk plugin issue. Folks using Ionic/Angular are also seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946793/android-build-failed-after-adding-crosswalk-to-ionic)

Comment: I don't believe the link is the solution.  Based on the comments in the link, 260 character path name is the problem.  However, my test project does not hit those limits.  `D:\erase\BlankCordovaApp8\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-armv7-debug.apk`

Comment: This is the Crosswalk plugin which uses a native (C/C++ not Java) implementation of the Chrome webview under the hood.  Also note that this is only a warning, so no action is required. The warning is related to this Android issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82187