# android-XYZTouristAttractions google's example: error while trying to compile

Tags: android

I' ve downloaded the google's sample project in the subject from this link:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions

When trying to build this project i get this error (sorry for long trace):

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:Application:assembleDebug]
:Application:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Application:checkDebugManifest
:Application:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:compileLint
:Shared:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:checkReleaseManifest
:Shared:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils032Library UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Shared:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Shared:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareAndroidXYZTouristAttractionsMasterSharedUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132100Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase700Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation700Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps700Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable700Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils032Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareDebugDependencies
:Application:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Application:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:checkReleaseManifest
:Wearable:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareAndroidXYZTouristAttractionsMasterSharedUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132103Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComGoogleAndroidSupportWearable110Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils032Library UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Wearable:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Wearable:mergeReleaseResources
AAPT out(1092500865) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1092500865) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(682745170) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(682745170) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(682745170) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(682745170) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00189.png
AAPT out(682745170) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(682745170) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00170.png
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00173.png
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00166.png
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00167.png
AAPT out(1867061693) : No Delegate set : lost message:Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00167.pnghdpi\common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(50760915): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00167.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(50760915): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00165.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(50760915): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(50760915): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-mdpi\common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1144179795): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00164.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1144179795): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00166.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1144179795): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-mdpi\common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1144179795): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.support\wearable\1.1.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\generic_confirmation_00189.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-mdpi\common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1092500865): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.maps.android\android-maps-utils\0.3.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\bubble_mask.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-hdpi\common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(682745170): C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Dropbox\Federico Ponzi\Programmazione\Java\Android\AndroidStudio\android-XYZTouristAttractions-master\Wearable\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\6.5.87\res\drawable-xhdpi\common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
:Wearable:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':Wearable:mergeReleaseResources'.

Crunching Cruncher common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png failed, see logs
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 17.486 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Note: i had to cut the trace, due to space problems, the complete trace can be found here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions/issues/1

I have windows 8 with AS 1.2 and:

```
SDK build tools 22.0.1
SDK platform 22 and 4.4.W2 (api 20)
```

I've tried to redownload the whole project, and install build tools 21.1.2 and now the error is the same but with another file in that directory.

Comment: The error got reported twice (you and another). This is obviously a compile error from the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions/issues/2) filed on github, the problem is the path length being too long (also see [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875555/android-studio-wear-app-error-unable-to-open-png) question for a similar problem).