# Execution failed for task ':mergeArmv7DebugResources' cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have been building my application with

```
cordova build android
```

but after performing `npm install -g cordova-android-crosswalk`

I get a weird error beginning with 
Execution failed for task ':mergeArmv7DebugResources' cordova
Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There's an error about path length. This must be less than 240 characters.
So I resolved this changing my main app folder to C:\

This questions have the solution.
[Android Studio Wear App Error - Unable to Open PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875555/android-studio-wear-app-error-unable-to-open-png)

Comment: Thats correct! you can remove this "(I think)". Thx!